# How to make a singleton in CDI 1.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, weld, jboss-weld

I use weld 2.3.5 which supports CDI 1.2. I came across a problem that CDI beans, annotated with `@javax.inject.Singleton` are ignored by the container (`bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`).

After googling I still can't find information about singletons and CDI 1.2. Could anyone explain the situation and give example how to make singleton CDI bean with CDI 1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bean discovery mode `annotated`, CDI will only pick up bean annotated with so-called *bean defining annotations*. The [spec clearly defines these](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations) and as you might expect, `@Singleton` is not amongst them.

To make your singleton recognizable, easiest way would be to just **use discovery mode `all`** but I suppose you want to avoid that. In which case perhaps an **extension could be used** to register the annotated type of your singleton - CDI should be able to pick up from there.

Then again, the usage of CDI `@Singleton` is very limited/specific as it is a non-proxy pseudo-scope. **In most cases, `@ApplicationScoped` will do** exactly what you want anyway so make sure you consider that before doing any extra work.

Comment: I personally come from a Spring world where both singleton scope and non-proxied injection are the default. It is very strange that this is not only not the default in CDI, but also very hard to do. In my case `@ApplicationScoped` is not what I want, as I don't want proxied injection (I don't need it and it just adds more entries on the stack for all the bean-finding logic). CDI needs to add a way to discover annotated beans _including_ `@Singleton`.

Comment: You can use `@Singleton` or the _actual_ default is `@Dependent` both of which do *not* have a proxy.

Comment: Yes, but `@Singleton`-annotated beans are not auto-discovered when discovery mode is set to "annotated". Getting auto-discoverable, non-proxied beans does not seem possible in CDI.

Comment: I would still recommend you to go with `@ApplicationScoped`, the proxy is disputable (if any) overhead. Unless you perform magic tricks that would require you to unwrap the proxy, you should be good. Other than that, you would have to have an extension that will either register that bean programatically with your desired scope or perhaps change scope on an existing one. Or maybe you could play around with producer method creating that bean as singleton for that should work as well. Both solution are inferior to simply using application scoped though.

Answer (score 2):

When discovery-mode = annotated, Weld does not identify beans with `@Singleton` and so does not load them, because `@Singleton` is not a normal scope.

If you want to have a Singleton with CDI, use **`@ApplicationScoped`**

Comment: When you inject an `@ApplicationScoped` bean, it injects a proxy. That may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is an old question and probably my solution comes too late :)

Just create a stereotype like this:

```
@Stereotype
@Singleton
@Target( TYPE )
@Retention( RUNTIME )
@interface SingletonBean
{
}
```

... and use it like this:

```
@SingletonBean
class MyBean
{
}
```

This way, MyBean will be discovered when `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`; no proxy involved.