# java.inject.singleton is not working for injection

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-7

javax.inject.Singleton is not working with wildfly (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final).And throws

> "WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type..."

exception on start up.

on the other hand javax.ejb.Singleton and javax.enterprise.context.Dependent works fine.

this one gets WELD exception.

```
@Singleton //javax.inject.Singleton
public class SimpleClass { ... }
```

These two below is just fine.

```
@Singleton // javax.ejb.Singleton
public class SimpleClass {... }

@Singleton // javax.enterprise.context.Dependent
public class SimpleClass {... }
```

what am i missing ??

Comment: The last annotation reads `@Singleton // javax.enterprise.context.Dependent` - I guess it should be `@Dependent // javax.enterprise.context.Dependent`? And although it seems strange that `@Singleton` is not working, why don't you use `@ApplicationScoped`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a singleton in CDI 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097337/how-to-make-a-singleton-in-cdi-1-2)