# Inject singleton to ApplicationScoped

Tags: singleton, cdi, application-scope

Can anyone explain why i can't inject Singleton bean to ApplicationScoped bean in Weld/CDI ? Got exception like - `WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SomeSingletonBean with qualifiers @Default` ..

Comment: The exception indicates that your `SomeSingletonBean` is not being discovered by CDI. You didn't mention versions or discovery mode, but I'd guess you are in `annotated` mode where each bean needs a [bean defining annotation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0#bean_defining_annotations) - `@Singleton` isn't among them for historical reasons. You can workaround that by having a [CDI stereotype](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0#stereotypes) with `@Singleton` scope on it. All stereotypes are bean defining annotations.

Comment: oh, I've found your answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097337/how-to-make-a-singleton-in-cdi-1-2. Thanks a lot!